# How to determine output values of a parameter using an algorithm/equation?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am using a chlorophyll-a algorithm to retrieve chlorophyll-a concentration in a lake using Sentinel 2A (S2_SR). How do I find the relative chl-a concentration for a certain pixel? I tried clicking on it using the inspector tool but I don't think this displays the correct concentration. I am fairly new to GEE and Java. For the code, I am first masking the water by using an advanced water extraction index (AWEI) and then applying the chl on top of the mask. The code I am using is below:

```
var roi = 
    ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[146.9781, -35.9226],
    [147.4368, -35.9201],
    [147.44051, -36.26673],
    [146.97417, -36.26873]]]);
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

// Map the function over one year of data and take the median.
// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterDate('2021-09-23', '2021-09-26')
 // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
 .filterBounds(roi)
  .map(maskS2clouds)
  
print (collection)

//RGB generation
var median = collection.median()
var clipped = median.clip(roi)


//Mask water using AWEI
var AWEI = clipped.expression('4 *(green - swir1) - 0.25 * nir + 2.75 * swir2',
{
  'green': clipped.select('B3'),
  'nir': clipped.select ('B8'),
  'swir1':clipped.select('B11'),
  'swir2':clipped.select ('B12')
});

var awei_Masked = AWEI.updateMask(AWEI.gt(0.0));

//Specify NDCI
var NDCIeq = clipped.expression ('((B5-B4)/(B5+B4))',
{
  B4: clipped.select('B4'),
  B5: clipped.select('B5'),
});

//Display NDCI on masked AWEI
//var NDCI1 = NDCIeq.updateMask(AWEI);

//Specify chl-a equation
var cheq = clipped.expression ('exp(7.33-0.004*b2-0.05*(b3/b12)+0.01*(b4/b11))',
{
  b2: clipped.select('B2'),
  b3: clipped.select('B3'),
  b4: clipped.select('B4'),
  b11:clipped.select('B11'),
  b12:clipped.select('B12'),
});

//Display chl-a on masked AWEI
var Chl = cheq.updateMask(AWEI);

//Display AWEI
//var AweiViz = {min: 0.00, max:1, palette: ['white', '1F1572']};
Map.addLayer (awei_Masked);

//Display Chl
var pal = {min: -0.3, max: 0.3, palette: ['2a186c','14439c','206e8b','3c9387','5ab978','aad85c','fdef9a']};
Map.addLayer(Chl, pal, 'Chl');
```

Comment: Your workflow seems to be correct, did you double check the expression you are applying? perhaps test on a pixel (get the band values) and test it in excel or something to make sure you implemented it correctly.

Comment: @jobbo90 Thank you for your comment! As I'm new to GEE and the whole remote sensing business, could you please elaborate on what you mean by testing it out? Do I just download the csv of a pixel from the RGB image and compare the excel and GEE generated graphs?

Comment: You can use the inspector tool on the layers you add to a map. If you add the original multispectral image to the map you can see the corresponding bandvalues and resulting Chl values for the clicked position. If you use these values in excel you should be able to replicate the Chl value, or something went wrong with your formula implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm a bit confused sorry. So I measure up the corresponding band values (RGB?) against the value of chl-a shown? And when you say use, does that mean plot them against each other? Is there anyway I can contact you via email?